# Unable create a custom keyboard shortcut in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys

I'm using 12.04 64bit on a Dell Latitude E6410. I want to create a custom keyboard shortcut.

Now I found out some articles that says you can create a custom keyboard shortcut using the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. But I can't create any custom shortcut. The status is showing as "**disabled**". Ideally it should show "**accelerated**" and then wait for my keyboard combination.

Answer (score 2):

Just click directly on the word "disabled" and it will change to "New accelerator...". Then press the key combination you would like to use for that command. From the help comment at the bottom of keyboard / shortcuts window:

"To edit a shortcut, click the row and hold down the new keys or press Backspace to clear"

Comment: That's precisely the problem. Even if I select the key shortcut, the **disabled** doesn't change to **new accelerator**.

Comment: This is very strange; it works for me. Which shortcut are you trying to edit? Did you try another one? Or editing an existing shortcut?

Comment: @linuxandunix This works for me when I click directly on the "Disabled" text.  If I click anywhere else, it brings-up the shortcut command definition.

Comment: Yeah,yeah, I know....look at how old the post is. BUT!...new to Ubuntu, I followed instructions from many posters on many sites and guides re: assigning custom hotkeys - and **continually** came up sucking wind. (and according to google, folks are still coming up empty!) And until BryceAtNetwork23 specifically noted that you must click **ON THE WORD "DISABLED"**, it just wasn't happening. Thanks for being specific, Bryce. You wouldn't believe the commands I've tried and the utilities I've upgraded following posters' instructions! Then here's this actually-helpful poster. Ya see how simple it m